# Magento 2 customer session implementation

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer-session

anybody know how magento 2 customer session implemented? Is this based on cookie expire time? Or Is this based on PHP Session? Because i encountered an issue while browsing the magento store customer gets sign out automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is set to a default of 3,600 seconds (one hour) for all customers by default.

My recommendation is to change this to a longer time, such as one day or a week.

You can set it here: 
Stores --> Configuration --> Web --> Default Cookie Sessions

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image: Default Cookie Session in Magento 2]

I hope this helps!

Comment: So even if i am active, customer will be logout after 1 hour?

Comment: Yes, the Magento 2 system, by default, will keep customers logged in for one hour or keep their cart alive for a single hour.